# Poincare Inequality for 1-Dimensional Problem.

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, sobolev-spaces

I am referring to the book `Introduction to Functional Analysis to Boundary Value Problems and Finite Element` by `Daya Reddy` *([page 233-234](http://books.google.de/books?id=aAVzpzQdJc8C&lpg=PP1&dq=introductory%20functional%20analysis%20with%20applications&pg=PA233#v=onepage&q&f=true))* for this question.

I am just stuck between parts of `Poincare's Inequality` proof as explained in the book. The statement is:

For any $u$ $\in$ $H^{k}(\Omega)$ where, $\Omega$ is $\mathbb{R} ^n$ with a smooth boundary (Lipschitz Continous) there exists constants $c_1$ & $c_2$ s.t. 
$$\|u\|_{H^k}^2 \le c_1 \int_\Omega \sum_{|\alpha| = k} \left(\mathscr{D}^\alpha u\right)^2  + c_2 \sum_{|\alpha| < k} \left( \int_\Omega \mathscr{D}^\alpha u \text{ } dx \right)^2 $$

where $\mathscr{D}$ is the differential operator, $H^k(\Omega) := \{f: \text{ } \mathscr{D}^\alpha f \text{ } \in \text{ } \mathscr{L}^2 (\Omega) \quad \forall \text{ } \alpha \textit{  such that   } | \alpha | \le k  \}$

For $ \quad n = 1 \Rightarrow \Omega = (a, b)$, we can write:
$$\|u\|_{H^k}^2 \le c_1 \int_a^b \left(\frac{d^ku}{dx^k}\right)^2dx \quad  + \quad c_2 \sum_{j < k} \left(\int_a^b\frac{d^ju}{dx^j}\right)^2dx $$

For $\quad (\eta , \xi) \quad in \quad (a, b) \quad | \quad \eta < \xi$
$$ [u(\xi) - u(\eta)] = \int_\eta^\xi u' dx \quad \Rightarrow \quad [u(\xi) - u(\eta)]^2 = \left(\int_\eta^\xi u' dx \right)^2 $$ 
By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality,
$$[u(\xi) - u(\eta)]^2 = \left(\int_\eta^\xi (1)(u') dx \right)^2 \le \left(\int_\eta^\xi 1^2 dx \right)^2 \left(\int_\eta^\xi (u')^2 dx \right) \\ \le (b - a)\int_a^b(u')^2 dx $$

Now, we integrate with respect to $\xi $, keeping $\eta$ constant, and then with respect to $\eta$  to get

=================================================================

$$ (b-a)\left[\int_a^b u^2 (\xi) d\xi + \int_a^b u^2 (\eta) d\eta \right] - 2 \int_a^b u(\xi) d\xi \int_a^b u(\eta) d\eta \\ \le (b-a)^3 \int_a^b (u')^2 dx$$

=================================================================

I have been working on how we get to the expression (above). Please provide any suggestion you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you probably mean $\xi > \eta$?

The overall inequality is
$$
|u(\xi) - u(\eta)|^2 \leq (b-a)\int_a^b (u')^2~dx.
$$
Write this as
$$
u(\xi)^2 - 2 u(\xi)u(\eta) + u(\eta)^2 \leq (b-a)\int_a^b (u')^2~dx.
$$
Integrate in $\xi$ from $a$ to $b$. $u(\eta)^2$ does not depend on $\xi$, so we obtain a factor of $(b-a)$. Similarly with the integral on the right. Everything is nonnegative so we preserve the direction of the inequality. So we obtain
$$
\int_a^b u(\xi)^2~d\xi - 2 u(\eta)\int_a^b u(\xi)~d\xi + (b-a)u(\eta)^2 \leq (b-a)^2\int_a^b (u')^2~dx.
$$
Now do the same, but with respect to $\eta$:
$$
(b-a)\int_a^b u(\xi)^2~d\xi - 2 \int_a^b u(\eta)~d\eta\int_a^b u(\xi)~d\xi + (b-a)\int_a^b u(\eta)^2~d\eta \leq (b-a)^3\int_a^b (u')^2~dx.
$$
And we're done!

Comment: I can't believe the ans was so simple. Thanks !!!